# @Unroll is not working in maven test with Spock 1.2 and Groovy 2.5

Tags: maven, groovy, spock

We switched to Java 11 and we figured out that we need upgrade Spock to 1.2 and Groovy to 2.5, otherwise tests are not running on Java 11

But now, with the latest Spock, maven counts each @Unroll test as a single test and not according to the number of different parameters.

Comment: So it's not really "no working" (al all), but it behaves differently?  Or could you elaborate more on the actual error you get?  Is it just wrong numbers or not running tests at all?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It looks like all tests are running, but tests counting is not correct

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue to follow in spock: https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/945.
For me, downgrading groovy to 2.4.16 solved the issue.